# Ошибка "Переменная не определена"

Tags: 1с

При проверке ниже, указанного модуля

```
СтрокаТабличнойЧасти=элементы.ПереченьНоменклатуры.ТекущиеДанные; 
СтрокаТабличнойЧасти.Цена=РаботаСоСправочником.РозничнаяЦена 
(Объект.Дата,СтрокаТабличнойЧасти.Номенклатура); 
РаботаСДокументами.РассчитатьСумма(СтрокаТабличнойЧасти);
```

Появляется следующая ошибка:
{Документ.ОказаниеУслуг.Форма.ФормаДокумента.Форма(24,28)}: Переменная не определена (РаботаСоСправочником)
СтрокаТабличнойЧасти.Цена=<>РаботаСоСправочником.РозничнаяЦена  (Проверка: Тонкий клиент)

Подскажите пожалуйста из-за чего эта ошибка возникает и каким способом её можно решить.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что не определена переменная. Решать просто - использовать только созданные и известные переменные.

Comment: Благодарю. Вся проблема была в том, что у меня общий модуль назывался "РаботаСоСправочниками", а написал "РаботаСоСправочником")

Answer (score 0):

&НаСервере

```
 Функция  ПолучитьДанныеСайта()
       
    // Установим соединение https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_utf8.xml
    Соедининие = Новый HTTPСоединение("www.cbr-xml-daily.ru",443,,,,,
      Новый ЗащищенноеСоединениеOpenSSL);   
      
     Запрос = Новый HTTPЗапрос("/daily_utf8.xml");    
     
     Ответ = Соединение.Получить(Запрос);
     
     Если Ответ.КодСостояния <> 200 Тогда
         ВызватьИсключение "Ошибка получения данных с сайта";  
     КонецЕсли;
```

Выдает ошибку :

```
{Обработка.ЗагрузкаКурсовВалют.Форма.Форма.Форма(28,11)}: Переменная не определена (Соединение)
     Ответ = <<?>>Соединение.Получить(Запрос); (Проверка: Сервер)
```

Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а этот «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите.